# ThreeCSG don't give expected result

Tags: javascript, debugging, three.js

I want to create a simple app in three.js
For this app, I need to subtract two meshes and I have found that ThreeCSG can do this. But somehow I don't get the expected result.

I have copied the code from an example, but even this doesn't work properly.

Trying some other function like the union. But instead of merging two meshes into one it removes it.

link to ThreeCSG: https://github.com/chandlerprall/ThreeCSG/blob/master/ThreeCSG.js

[result that I get when subtracting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSN4s.png)

[result that I get when I use union](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbWNM.png)

```
var materialNormal = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial( { side: THREE.DoubleSide } );
var diceCube = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.BoxGeometry(10,10,10), materialNormal);

diceCube.position.x = 0;
diceCube.position.y = 5;
diceCube.position.z = 0;

diceCube.geometry.computeFaceNormals();
diceCube.geometry.computeVertexNormals();

var cubeBSP = new ThreeBSP(diceCube);

var sphereGeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(7.5,16,8);
var sphereMesh = new THREE.Mesh(sphereGeometry, materialNormal);

sphereMesh.scale.x = 0.17;
sphereMesh.scale.y = 0.17;
sphereMesh.scale.z = 0.17;

//coords of the spheres 
var xPositions = [ 0, 3 ]; // coordinates for xPositions of sphereMesh
var yPositions = [ 10, 10 ];
var zPositions = [ 0, 0 ];

var diceDots    = new THREE.Geometry();

for(var i = 0; i < xPositions.length; i++){
    sphereMesh.position.x   = xPositions[i];
    sphereMesh.position.y   = yPositions[i];
    sphereMesh.position.z   = zPositions[i];
    sphereMesh.updateMatrix();
    diceDots.merge( sphereMesh.geometry, sphereMesh.matrix );
}

var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0xffaa00 });
var dotsMesh = new THREE.Mesh(diceDots);
dotsMesh.geometry.computeFaceNormals();
dotsMesh.geometry.computeVertexNormals();

var dotsBSP = new ThreeBSP(dotsMesh);
var resultBSP = cubeBSP.subtract(dotsBSP);

result = resultBSP.toMesh(material);
scene.add(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution.
The threeCSG I used was corrupted this one works exactly how it must be done.

Link to working ThreeCSG: https://github.com/oathihs/ThreeCSG/blob/master/dist/THREE.CSG.js